# LoadPixel function is not working as expected on p5?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, pixel, p5.js

I am trying to pixelate an image in p5 based on conditional thresholding on the greyscale/brightness values of the RGB of an input image. I am using 'Load Pixels ()' function from the libaray. I am scaling down the original image and then scaling it back up for quick loading.

However it seems that the brightness is not being detected if the image? The image prints out in one tone.

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong

```
    let video;
let playing = true;

let w = 620*1.2 ;
let h = 320*1.2 ;
let vScale = 12;
let inc = (255/8) ; // 255/10

let purple = '#7a45ff';
let lightgrey = '#f0f6f7';
let darkgrey = '#231F24';

//darkest
let thresh_0 = 0
let thresh_10 = thresh_0 + inc
let thresh_20 = thresh_10 + inc
let thresh_30 = thresh_20 + inc
let thresh_40 = thresh_30 + inc
let thresh_50 = thresh_40 + inc
let thresh_60 = thresh_50 + inc
let thresh_70 = thresh_60 + inc
let thresh_80 = thresh_70 + inc
// light

let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('test_!fun.png');
}
function setup() {
   createCanvas(w, h);
   pixelDensity(2);
}

function draw(){
   background(lightgrey)

   img.loadPixels();
   
   for (let y = 0; y <= img.height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x <= img.width; x++) {
        
         let index = (x + y * img.width) * 4
         let r = img.pixels[index + 0];
         let g = img.pixels[index + 1];
         let b = img.pixels[index + 2];
         let a = 255;

         let brightness = (r + g + b) / 3

         noStroke()

         //  start defining threshold
         if (brightness <= thresh_0) {
            fill(lightgrey)
            square(x * vScale, y * vScale, 16)
         }
         else if (brightness <= thresh_10) {
            noStroke()
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 3.2);
         } else
         if (brightness <= thresh_20) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 6);
            fill(lightgrey)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 3.2);
         } else
         if (brightness <= thresh_30) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 6);
         } else
         if (brightness <= thresh_40) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 8.8);
            fill(lightgrey)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 6);
         } else
         if (brightness <= thresh_50) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 8.8);
            fill(lightgrey)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 5.6);
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 3.2);
         } else
          if (brightness <= thresh_60) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 10);
            fill(lightgrey)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 5);
         } else
         if (brightness <= thresh_70) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 10);
            fill(lightgrey)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 3.2);
         } else
         if (brightness <= thresh_80) {
            fill(purple)
            ellipse(x * vScale + vScale/2, y * vScale + vScale/2, 10);
         }

       
      }
    
   }
   image(img, 0, 0, w / vScale, h / vScale);
}
```